# VBA code causing excel lagging

Tags: performance, excel, lag, vba

My code below is used to decrements date based on the first date entered, and if column B is filled. As the data imported to Excel is very large, so this calculation is now causing my excel to lag. Is there a way to speed it up??

```
For i = 1 To rowNow - 3

newDate = DateAdd("d", -i, oldDate)

For Each Cell In Range("A:A").Cells

If IsEmpty(Cell) = True And IsEmpty(Range("B:B")) = False Then Cell.Value = newDate: Exit For

Next
Next
```

Comment: For each iteration of your loop you are potentially checking a million cells - really necessary?

Comment: @SJR sorry, I'm kinda new to vba. do you mean the For Each function is causing this? I did tried to change this, but then , it wont decrements the date if i dont use that function

Comment: Yes your inner loop - anyway see two suggested solutions below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this,depending on what's in column B:

```
For i = 1 To rowNow - 3
    newDate = DateAdd("d", -i, oldDate)
    With Range("A:A")
        On Error Resume Next
        Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks), .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(, -1))(1).Value = newDate
    End With
Next i
```